# Why is would incorrect in "He wishes he would live near the sea."?

Tags: wish

> He likes to swim. He wishes he would live near the sea. (Incorrect)
>   He likes to swim. He wishes he lived near the sea. (Correct)

Why is the first one incorrect, it is something that can change, the person can move

Comment: You could also use "He wishes he *could* live near the sea."

Answer (score 1):

Because *XXX wish(es) YYYY would ...* is used only where the person doing the wishing is not the person they're wishing about.

> *I wish he would live near the sea.*

is fine, but not

> **He wishes he would live near the sea.*

Comment: I wish that you lived close by  the person doing the wishing is not the person they're wishing about. and would is not used is it because it is not possible and can't change

Comment: I said the form with _would_ is only possible when the person is different. I didn't say that it's compulsory then. There are other constraints.

Comment: incredible English!